# Cannot instantiate class HomePage

Tags: selenium, testng

Hi I'm struggling to see what I've done wrong I'm trying out selenium webdriver with TestNG everytime really basic stuff but I dont understand why when I put everything into my before chrome fires up. But I want my code to be neater and less clumsy. It appears I need to stick the driver in my class so it has a global affect. Instead of instatiating a new web driver in every new test I create. Is there a better way to do it?

```
Cannot instantiate class HomePage
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:363)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:275)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:191)


  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    import org.testng.annotations.*;


    public class HomePage {
         WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();



        @BeforeTest
        public void beforeTest() {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/webdrivers/chromedriver81/chromedriver.exe");

            driver.get("http://www.dotdotloans.co.uk");
        }


        @Test
        public void verify36monthloan3250() {

            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Tarife")).click();
            // confirm monthly repayment
            // credit charge 2 decimal places
            //total to pay 2 decimal places
            //APR
            //Click Apply now
            //verify string has 3250 and 36 months

            System.out.println("Welcome");


        }

        @AfterTest
        public void AfterTest() {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us the full stacktrace please

Comment: https://gist.github.com/afcbpeter1/648319449bb2d1e1e4316c57f836b224

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` is executed before you set the required property to set path to executable:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/webdrivers/chromedriver81/chromedriver.exe");
```

You can either set the property value in static initialization block

```java
public class HomePage{

  static{
    System.setProperty(blah-blah);
  }

  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

  // ..

}
```

or create new driver within `@BeforeTest` after you have set executable path property value. **The latter is more natural way**.

**P.S.** - I am not sure but even if use the fix with static initialization your code might not work correctly since TestNG might re-use the test class object and since you're **quitting** your driver the second test of your class would not be able to start (if you will add the second test).